# Which ip address should be sent to reCAPTCHA?

Tags: php, proxy, ip-address, recaptcha

In Google's [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify), it is possible to supply an optional ip address when verifying that the user is not a robot.

1. What do you gain by supplying the user's ip address?
2. When supplying an ip address, which address should be used? Always `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`? What if the user is behind a proxy, or the site is behind a load balancer? Is it then better to try to find the ip address closest to the user and use that instead? For example by looking at `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']`, etc.

Comment: Sidenote: why does reCAPTCHA need the sit to send the IP? The user's browser interacts directly with reCAPTCHA so Google already has access to the user's IP right?

Comment: 1. It's indeed unclear what you would gain from that. 2. Conceivably the user may appear to be a different IP address to Google than to you, so this would just lead to a lot of false positives.